# firebase - Use updateProfile whenever a user signup

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with firebase, I want when a user creates a user for the first time, add him to updateProfile, personal details.

This is the code I'm trying to do but the code is not running, it does not work for me.

The part with the `currentUser` does not work, I do not understand why, I also do not get an error.

```js
signupUser = async () => {
    
    const newUser = {
      email: 'test@mail.com',
      password: '123456'
    };

    await signup(newUser);
  }
```

**call to signup in nodejs**

```js
    export const signup = (newUser) => (dispatch) => {
        axios
            .post('/signup', newUser)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
```

**signup - nodejs**

```js
//basically call to this function to signup

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
    const newUser = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    };
    firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
        .then((data) => {
            const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                    const name = `${"adding some private information"}`;
                    currentUser.updateProfile({
                        displayName: name,
                    })
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log("sign in successfully")
                        });
                        
            return data.user.getIdToken();    
        })
        .then((token) => {
            return db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).set("test");
        })
    .then(() => {
      return res.status(201).json({ token });
    })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue looks to be that you aren't return the promise from `currentUser.updateProfile`, ensuring it successfully completes. Try the following by returning the `Promise` from that method:

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  };

  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then((data) => {
      const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      const name = `${"adding some private information"}`;

      return currentUser
        .updateProfile({
          displayName: name,
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("sign in successfully");
          return data.user.getIdToken();
        });
    })
    .then((token) => {
      return db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).set("test");
    })
    .then(() => {
      return res.status(201).json({ token });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // probably send an error back?
      // return res.status(500).json({ message: 'error' });
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```